# Creating three groups of legends in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am plotting 5 elements in my graph:

- the occurrencies of 3 types of crime (anti-social behaviour, theft and violence)
- 3 smooth conditional means (linear model in geom_smooth() ) - i.e. one for each type of crime to study the relationship between the unemployment rate and each type of crime
- 1 unemployment rate line

So I am trying to create three legend titles as follows:

1. **Crime** (*"anti-social behaviour", "theft", "violence"*)
2. **Smooth conditional mean** (*"anti-social behaviour", "theft", "violence"*)
3. **no name** (*"Unemployment rate"*)

So far, I've managed to add the Crime legend.

However, no matter where I put add `linetype = "`, the smooth conditional means won't appear in the legend. Also, if I try to add `labs(linetype = "LEGEND TITLE")` after the three `geom_smooth()`, the unemployment rate legend title changes instead (as shown in the output below).

Here's the output (the dashed lines refer to the three `geom_smooth()`, and the colour matches the crime type they are calculating the smooth conditional mean of.

[image]

This is the code I used; as you can see, I tried adding `linetype =` both inside and outside `aes()`. It just won't show up in the legend regardless.

So the question is, where should I put linetype = "" so that it shows the name of each smooth conditional mean??

```
ggplot(mapping=aes(Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Crime_occurrences, colour = Crime),
            size = 1, data = cr_grouped) + #this is the crime legend and it works a charm
  geom_line(lwd = 1, mapping = aes(x = Date, y = rescale(Unemployment.rate, to = out_range, 
                                                         from = in_range),
                                   linetype = "Unemployment rate"), #this shows up alright
            data = ur_grouped) +
  labs(linetype = "Legend") + #this shows up only if I delete labs() under the 3 geom_smooth()
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F, aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrences, group=1), 
              linetype = "123456", col = "darkgreen", lty = 6, data=smooth_theft)+ #ex outside aes()
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F, aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrences, group=1,
                                      linetype = "ABCD"), #example inside aes()
              col = "red", lty = 6, data=smooth_antisocial)+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F, aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrences, group=1), 
              col = "blue3", lty = 6, data=smooth_violence)+
  labs(linetype = "Smooth Conditional Means") + #this renames the labs() created for unemployment
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2020-10-01"), by="1 month"),
               date_labels = '%m %Y') +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = 
                       sec_axis(~ rescale(.x, to = in_range, from = out_range), 
                                name = "Unemployment Rate (%)")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle =- 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

Thanks for any help you can give!

DPUT:

**cr_grouped**

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17897, 17897, 17897, 17928, 
17928, 17928, 17956, 17956, 17956, 17987, 17987, 17987, 18017, 
18017, 18017, 18048, 18048, 18048, 18078, 18078, 18078, 18109, 
18109, 18109, 18140, 18140, 18140, 18170, 18170, 18170, 18201, 
18201, 18201, 18231, 18231, 18231, 18262, 18262, 18262, 18293, 
18293, 18293, 18322, 18322, 18322, 18353, 18353, 18353, 18383, 
18383, 18383, 18414, 18414, 18414, 18444, 18444, 18444, 18475, 
18475, 18475, 18506, 18506, 18506, 18536, 18536, 18536), class = "Date"), 
    Crime = c("Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences", 
    "Anti-social behaviour", "Theft", "Violence and sexual offences"
    ), Crime_occurrences = c(59426L, 90521L, 66296L, 61187L, 
    85416L, 61955L, 67810L, 93273L, 70843L, 68936L, 87633L, 66300L, 
    71379L, 89408L, 69906L, 72021L, 86315L, 71564L, 83705L, 86819L, 
    74969L, 78481L, 83309L, 69450L, 67932L, 81552L, 68740L, 69469L, 
    90307L, 70696L, 60692L, 87529L, 69011L, 53728L, 82404L, 69231L, 
    59571L, 88523L, 70824L, 57038L, 83460L, 69155L, 70861L, 71699L, 
    68956L, 135439L, 44984L, 58431L, 138529L, 47934L, 65947L, 
    102061L, 53208L, 70050L, 88014L, 62855L, 76773L, 91811L, 
    65687L, 76171L, 81958L, 67925L, 72268L, 84434L, 69627L, 70698L
    )), row.names = c(NA, -66L), groups = structure(list(Date = structure(c(17897, 
17928, 17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 
18201, 18231, 18262, 18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 
18475, 18506, 18536), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(
    1:3, 4:6, 7:9, 10:12, 13:15, 16:18, 19:21, 22:24, 25:27, 
    28:30, 31:33, 34:36, 37:39, 40:42, 43:45, 46:48, 49:51, 52:54, 
    55:57, 58:60, 61:63, 64:66), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, 22L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

---

**ur_grouped**

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 
18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 18231, 18262, 
18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18506, 18536
), class = "Date"), Unemployment.rate = c(4.85019120720378, 4.87826349489932, 
4.72619911892442, 4.82962291533381, 4.78037962696207, 4.75317591530959, 
4.53739659597437, 4.58692391687679, 4.57052637882086, 4.56628766844258, 
4.60997237871127, 4.58039236078879, 4.73224909680535, 4.73446295980473, 
4.62619907452877, 4.44434845370539, 4.53780319184207, 4.46033205030955, 
4.57680473216631, 5.01205713295936, 5.42174180050248, 5.75623503556053
)), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

---

**OUT_RANGE and IN_RANGE** [out_range can be adjusted manually, I usually do out_range[2] <- X to check what value fits best for scaling purposes]

*out_range <- range(cr_grouped$Crime_occurrences)
in_range <- range(ur_grouped$Unemployment.rate)*

---

**smooth_theft**

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 
18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 18231, 18262, 
18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18506, 18536
), class = "Date"), Crime = c("Theft", "Theft", "Theft", "Theft", 
"Theft", "Theft", "Theft", "Theft", "Theft", "Theft", "Theft", 
"Theft", "Theft", "Theft", "Theft", "Theft", "Theft", "Theft", 
"Theft", "Theft", "Theft", "Theft"), Crime_occurrences = c(90521L, 
85416L, 93273L, 87633L, 89408L, 86315L, 86819L, 83309L, 81552L, 
90307L, 87529L, 82404L, 88523L, 83460L, 71699L, 44984L, 47934L, 
53208L, 62855L, 65687L, 67925L, 69627L)), row.names = c(NA, -22L
), groups = structure(list(Date = structure(c(17897, 17928, 17956, 
17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 18231, 
18262, 18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18506, 
18536), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
    18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

---

**smooth_antisocial:**

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17897, 17928, 17956, 17987, 
18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 18231, 18262, 
18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 18506, 18536
), class = "Date"), Crime = c("Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", 
"Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", 
"Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", 
"Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", 
"Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", 
"Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", 
"Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour", 
"Anti-social behaviour", "Anti-social behaviour"), Crime_occurrences = c(59426L, 
61187L, 67810L, 68936L, 71379L, 72021L, 83705L, 78481L, 67932L, 
69469L, 60692L, 53728L, 59571L, 57038L, 70861L, 135439L, 138529L, 
102061L, 88014L, 91811L, 81958L, 84434L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-22L), groups = structure(list(Date = structure(c(17897, 17928, 
17956, 17987, 18017, 18048, 18078, 18109, 18140, 18170, 18201, 
18231, 18262, 18293, 18322, 18353, 18383, 18414, 18444, 18475, 
18506, 18536), class = "Date"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 2L, 
    3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
    16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -22L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi dear, could you please use `dput(cr_grouped)`, `dput(ur_grouped)`, `dput(smooth_theft)`, `dput(smooth_antisocial)` and paste the output editing your question. Also what are `to = out_range,from = in_range` and `to = in_rangeH, from = out_rangeH`

Comment: Hello you! Just added everything (ignore in_rangeH and out_rangeH, they're supposed to not have that H at the end). Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try next code. First install the `ggnewscale` package. I have removed the last piece of code as you do not shared the data for that smoothed option but adding that would not be an issue. Here the code:

```
library(ggnewscale)
#Plot
ggplot(mapping=aes(Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Crime_occurrences, colour = Crime),
            size = 1, data = cr_grouped) +
  geom_line(lwd = 1, mapping = aes(x = Date,
                                   y = rescale(Unemployment.rate,
                                               to = out_range,
                                               from = in_range),
                                   linetype = "Unemployment rate"),
            data = ur_grouped) +
  labs(linetype = "Legend") +
  new_scale_color()+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F,
              aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrences, group=1,
                  color='smooth_theft'), 
              lty = 6, data=smooth_theft)+
  geom_smooth(method = 'lm',se=F,
              aes(x=Date,y = Crime_occurrences, group=1,
                  color='smooth_antisocial'),
              lty = 6, data=smooth_antisocial)+
  labs(colour = "Smooth Conditional Means") + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c('darkgreen','red'))+
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2020-10-01"), by="1 month"),
               date_labels = '%m %Y') +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = 
                       sec_axis(~ rescale(.x, to = in_range, from = out_range), 
                                name = "Unemployment Rate (%)")) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle =- 90, vjust = 0.5))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: How do you even find this stuff so quickly??? I owe you loads of coffees. Will pay my dues at some point

Comment: @Lactuca It is practice dear, I use that kind of plots everyday so it is easy helping people like you :) Sounds nice the fact about coffees ;) Let me know if that code worked for you!

Comment: It did! I think I should be done for now phew

Comment: @Lactuca That is nice, if at any point of time the coffees are still available, you can check my profile there is an option for that hahaha! Nice to help you!